# Untar multiple files in different directories

Tags: tar, find, cms

am trying to perform an update on multiple site that use an open source CMS but untaring a patch file in each sites httpdocs directory. My plan was to perform a find for the patch file then untar using the following command:

```
find . -name "patchfile.tar.gz" -exec tar -xzvf {} \; -print
```

but it doesnt seem to work successfully

anyone have any ideas as to why not?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are extracting the tar file in the current directory, not where the patch file is. You can write a small wrapper to extract the files in the desired directory, e.g.

```
#!/bin/bash
DIR=`dirname $1`
cd $DIR
tar xzf $1
```

now the search command can be

```
find ... -exec tar.sh {} \; ...
```